# what is fast way to download datauri background images in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Lot of times images are inlined on websites, either img tag's src attribute has data url string instead of link or css background property value is url(..) that contains data url instead of url.

how do i download that picture, especially when for background images.

right now i copy the data url manually and find converter through google.

Comment: Do you want to do it programmatically? Or do you just want a better way to do it manually?

Comment: Not sure if you mean this, but you could open the Network-Tab in your Devtools (e.g. Chrome), reload the page and search for the image in the list of downloaded items. You can also filter for images.

Comment: @maxpaj if there is easy code then yea...

Comment: if image is inlined then it wont show in downloaded items

Comment: How to devtools Copy image as data URI programmably

Answer (score 1):

**Chrome**: find it in inspector, select that element, find background style with data url on right side, right click, choose "open in new tab", new tab should appear with that image, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

**Firefox**: right click + view background image + <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

p.s. Firefox way is ~37x faster.

Comment: im unable to paste as it's too long i think

Comment: @MuhammadUmer looks like paste works only for small images, i edited answer.